# Android Preserve View visibility when screen orientation changes?

Tags: android, view, orientation, preserve

I'm new to this how to handle app when you turn your gadget and I have a problem.

- I'm inflating table rows into a table.
- They are gone (View.GONE) when `onCreate()`.
- They appear on a `click` of a button.
- **but disappear when screen orientation changes.**

Is there a way to preserve Visibility of a View when orientation changes?

I've not yet worked with `onSaveInstanceState()` or similar, just `onCreate()` for now.

Any suggestions would appreciated.

I'm eager to learn new stuff
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this happens because when you rotate the device the `Activity` is restarted and your `onCreate` is called again making the `TableRow` hidden again, if you have the same layout for both screens then there is no need to do so just add below line in your manifest in Activity node

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Comment: Thank you ingsaurabh. Worked like a charm! I've come across this but didn't know what keyboard has to do with this. Thanks a million!

Comment: KeyBoard has to doing nothing with this but if your activity contains an EditText as first container then it will show Keyboard if this is not mentioned

Comment: Sorry I tought I have tried this orientation flag only but I guess I did something else wrong. I thank you for the explanation it will come very handy. Best regards.

Comment: Where exactly should I put this line? It didn't work for me in the activity declaration line.

Comment: you should add `screenSize` too. `"keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"`